# Can I use the Google Cloud Vision API without activating the free trial?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Is there a way to test the Google Vision API in an application without activating my free trial?

I am trying to use the API in a sample test application, but I can't enable the Vision API without having a valid billing method added.

Error Message:  " The API requires a valid billing method."

When I try to enable billing from the Dashboard - Billing - It redirect to a page where I have to input my information in order to "Try Cloud Platform for free" and I have to click on a button with the message - "Start my free trial". Is there a way to enable billing without starting my free trial?

I just want to use the free tier (doesn't matter if I would have to put in my credit card) without 'wasting' my free trial -- I think so much money for trial could be spent better elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible...with a [billing account set up](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en)...

> To create a new billing account:
>
> 1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console and sign in or, if you don't already
>    have an account, sign up.
> 2. Open the console menu and select **Billing**.
> 3. Click the **New billing account** button. (Note
>    that if this is not your first billing account, first you need to open
>    the billing account list by clicking the name of your existing billing
>    account near the top of the page, and then clicking **Manage billing
>    accounts**.)
> 4. Enter the name of the billing account and enter your
>    billing information. The options you see depend on the country of your
>    billing address. Note that for United States accounts, you cannot
>    change tax status after the account is created.
> 5. Click Submit and enable billing.

Now  by enabling billing for your test project, you'll have the option to use a billing account...the one you just set up.

Comment: I have followed these steps (as already described in the question)   and when I try to add a New Billing Account (step 3) it redirects me to the free trial page - where after input my data it has the "Start my free trial" button. Screenshots would be helpful to better explain?

Comment: I haven't got a new account to test. You should reach out to support then I guess https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Comment: In order to be able to send a message to support you need to add a billing id for the project (which obviously I don't have since I cant enable billing)

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your trial account anytime, and you'll immediately have access to standard service quotas. If you upgrade to a paid account before the 60-day trial period ends, any remaining amount of your initial trial credit remains in your account. [See this link](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/upgrade-paid-account).

Comment: I am not looking to upgrade my trial account, what I want is to enable billing without activating the trial (so I could activate the trial at a later date when I want to explore all the feature offered by the GCP)

Comment: Based on Free trial eligibility criteria described on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-eligibility-sign-up): *The free trial is a one-time introduction to the platform for new customers. If you have never been a paying customer of Google Cloud Platform and have not previously signed up for the free trial, you are eligible.* Therefore, if you enable billing you will be considered a paying customer, and consequently won't be eligible for free trial. I hope this answers your question.